# Decode from VP8 video frame to RGB

Tags: rgb, yuv, webm, vp8, libvpx

In my application, we need to display the video frame on the screen. I use libvpx to decode a video from WebM, but frame is decoded to YUV format (VPX_IMG_FMT_I420 according to the documentation). I need to output format is RGB and the documentation says a image supported a RGB format (VPX_IMG_FMT_RGB24). I have a formula for translating YUV->RGB: 
R = Y + 1.13983 * (V - 128); 
G = Y - 0.39465 * (U - 128) - 0.58060 * (V - 128);
B = Y + 2.03211 * (U - 128);
But I think is too many conversions VP8->YUV->RGB. Is there a method for set a output frame format for conversion function?

Comment: Someone is actually using VP8? Looking at the API, I see no such option...

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean: WebM is actually using VP8.

Comment: Just my bad sense of humor; ON2 have never really managed to get a foothold of the video market with their codecs. VP7 just disappeared; perhaps it's different with VP8...

Comment: Maybe VP8 will disappear. But VP3 (currently the Theora) alive. And Google bought On2 and uses this format (VP8) as a standard. Thus, VP8 can live longer, IMHO.
However, if after one year VP8 will be gone, I need to use webm + VP8 in my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford using [Intel's IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) library, here is some CPU friendly piece of code that you can try and apply in your project:

```
unsigned char*  mpRGBBuffer;

void VPXImageToRGB24(vpx_image_t* pImage, bool isUsingBGR)
{
   const unsigned int rgbBufferSize = pImage->d_w * pImage->d_h * 3;

   mpRGBBuffer - allocate your raw RGB buffer...

    const IppiSize  sz          = { pImage->d_w, pImage->d_h };
    const Ipp8u*    src[3]      = { pImage->planes[PLANE_Y],     pImage->planes[PLANE_U],     pImage->planes[PLANE_V]       };
    int             srcStep[3]  = { pImage->stride[VPX_PLANE_Y], pImage->stride[VPX_PLANE_U], pImage->stride[VPX_PLANE_V]   };

    if (isUsingBGR) ippiYCbCr420ToBGR_8u_P3C3R(src, srcStep, pDest, pImage->d_w * 3, sz);
    else            ippiYCbCr420ToRGB_8u_P3C3R(src, srcStep, pDest, pImage->d_w * 3, sz);
}
```

If you dont want to use IPP, here is [a link](http://swift.im/git/swift-contrib/tree/Swiften/ScreenSharing/VP8Decoder.cpp?h=dknn/rtp&id=dce09fe24d55d67f60d7bc691e285897f1d64fc2) to some working peace of core that could really be usefull. Tested this, works for 100% but not sure about the CPU cost.

Here is the code from the link above (in case link fails...)

```
inline int clamp8(int v)
{
    return std::min(std::max(v, 0), 255);
} 

Image VP8Decoder::convertYV12toRGB(const vpx_image_t* img)
{
    Image rgbImg(img->d_w, img->d_h);
    std::vector<uint8_t>& data = rgbImg.data;

    uint8_t *yPlane = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_Y];
    uint8_t *uPlane = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_U];
    uint8_t *vPlane = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_V];

    int i = 0;
    for (unsigned int imgY = 0; imgY < img->d_h; imgY++) {
        for (unsigned int imgX = 0; imgX < img->d_w; imgX++) {
            int y = yPlane[imgY * img->stride[VPX_PLANE_Y] + imgX];
            int u = uPlane[(imgY / 2) * img->stride[VPX_PLANE_U] + (imgX / 2)];
            int v = vPlane[(imgY / 2) * img->stride[VPX_PLANE_V] + (imgX / 2)];

            int c = y - 16;
            int d = (u - 128);
            int e = (v - 128);

            // TODO: adjust colors ?

            int r = clamp8((298 * c           + 409 * e + 128) >> 8);
            int g = clamp8((298 * c - 100 * d - 208 * e + 128) >> 8);
            int b = clamp8((298 * c + 516 * d           + 128) >> 8);

            // TODO: cast instead of clamp8

            data[i + 0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(r);
            data[i + 1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(g);
            data[i + 2] = static_cast<uint8_t>(b);

            i += 3;
        }
    }
    return rgbImg;
}
```